# Como faço para construir a função summary() no R para um data frame?

Tags: r, funções, if, summary

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma

```
          dados<- c(10,18,19,15,21,34,45,64,20,21,39)
          resumo <- function(x) {
                  min(x)
                  max(x)
             n <- length(x)
             s <- sort(x)
                  ifelse(n%%2==1,
                  s[(n+1)/2],
                  mean(s[n/2+0:1]))
                  mean(x)
                  range(x)
              }
              resumo(dados)
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está uma possível função `resumo_df`.

1. Primeiro verifica se o argumento `X` é um data.frame e dá error se não for;
2. De seguida, determina quais as colunas numéricas;
3. E para cada coluna numérica chama a função interna `f` onde as contas são feitas.

Depois é só juntar tudo com `do.call/cbind`.

```
resumo_df <- function(X, na.rm = FALSE){
  f <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
    xbar <- mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    s <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    cv <- s/xbar
    c(
      Min = min(x, na.rm = na.rm),
      Mediana = median(x, na.rm = na.rm),
      Max = max(x, na.rm = na.rm),
      Ampl = diff(range(x, na.rm = na.rm)),
      Var = var(x, na.rm = na.rm),
      DP = sd(x, na.rm = na.rm),
      CV = cv,
      N = length(unique(x))
    )
  }
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(X))
  i <- sapply(X, is.numeric)
  Y <- lapply(X[i], f, na.rm = na.rm)
  do.call(cbind.data.frame, Y)
}

resumo_df(1:10)
# Error in resumo_df(1:10) : inherits(X, "data.frame") is not TRUE 

resumo_df(tibble::as_tibble(iris))
#        Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#Min        4.3000000   2.0000000     1.000000   0.1000000
#Mediana    5.8000000   3.0000000     4.350000   1.3000000
#Max        7.9000000   4.4000000     6.900000   2.5000000
#Media      5.8433333   3.0573333     3.758000   1.1993333
#Ampl       3.6000000   2.4000000     5.900000   2.4000000
#Var        0.6856935   0.1899794     3.116278   0.5810063
#DP         0.8280661   0.4358663     1.765298   0.7622377
#CV         7.0566023   7.0143836     2.128819   1.5734375
#N         35.0000000  23.0000000    43.000000  22.0000000

resumo_df(mtcars)
#              mpg      cyl         disp         hp       drat         wt      qsec        vs        am      gear     carb
#Min     10.400000 4.000000    71.100000   52.00000  2.7600000  1.5130000 14.500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 3.0000000 1.000000
#Mediana 19.200000 6.000000   196.300000  123.00000  3.6950000  3.3250000 17.710000 0.0000000 0.0000000 4.0000000 2.000000
#Max     33.900000 8.000000   472.000000  335.00000  4.9300000  5.4240000 22.900000 1.0000000 1.0000000 5.0000000 8.000000
#Media   20.090625 6.187500   230.721875  146.68750  3.5965625  3.2172500 17.848750 0.4375000 0.4062500 3.6875000 2.812500
#Ampl    23.500000 4.000000   400.900000  283.00000  2.1700000  3.9110000  8.400000 1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 7.000000
#Var     36.324103 3.189516 15360.799829 4700.86694  0.2858814  0.9573790  3.193166 0.2540323 0.2489919 0.5443548 2.608871
#DP       6.026948 1.785922   123.938694   68.56287  0.5346787  0.9784574  1.786943 0.5040161 0.4989909 0.7378041 1.615200
#CV       3.333466 3.464598     1.861581    2.13946  6.7265860  3.2880837  9.988426 0.8680278 0.8141431 4.9979394 1.741270
#N       25.000000 3.000000    27.000000   22.00000 22.0000000 29.0000000 30.000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 3.0000000 6.000000
```